# SQL concatenation via a case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a CASE statement as follows.
This creates a string of two character substrings separated by a semi-colon as required and removes the trailing semi-colon via a custom function.

```
    CASE 
        WHEN ISNULL(mcp.N5_5_CARE_INTENT,'') <> 'X'
        THEN
        NULLIF(dbo.RemoveLastCharacter
        (COALESCE(mcp.N5_6_TREATMENT_TYPE_1 + ';','') + 
        COALESCE(mcp.N5_6_TREATMENT_TYPE_2 + ';','') +
        COALESCE(mcp.N5_6_TREATMENT_TYPE_3 + ';','') +
        COALESCE(mcp.N5_6_TREATMENT_TYPE_4 + ';','')),'')
        ELSE NULL
        END PlannedTreatmentType
```

But this doesn't go far enough because I want the two character substrings, and the eventual concatenation, to only consist of:

```
    '01', '02', '03', '05', '06'
```

If there is a substring which isn't one of these then NULL should be returned.

For instance

```
    01;05;06
```

is good, and so is

```
    06;01
```

but

```
    01;07
```

or

```
    09;08su
```

are not good

This has to be compatible with SQL2000. Thank you.

Comment: Please show sample data.  Why would you be getting values other than the ones you specified?

Comment: Gordon Linoff - the fields mcp.N5_6_TREATMENT_TYPE_1 to mcp.N5_6_TREATMENT_TYPE_4 can contain a variety of two character strings, but I only want to perform the concatenation if all of the two character substrings present consist of the five substrings listed.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to test each value before putting it in the string.  Also, you can use the `stuff()` approach instead of your function.

```
(CASE WHEN ISNULL(mcp.N5_5_CARE_INTENT,'') <> 'X'
      THEN stuff((case when mcp.N5_6_TREATMENT_TYPE_1 in ('01', '02', '03', '05', '06')
                       then ';'+mcp.N5_6_TREATMENT_TYPE_1 
                       else ''
                   end) +
                 (case when mcp.N5_6_TREATMENT_TYPE_2 in ('01', '02', '03', '05', '06')
                       then ';'+mcp.N5_6_TREATMENT_TYPE_2
                       else ''
                   end) +
                 (case when mcp.N5_6_TREATMENT_TYPE_3 in ('01', '02', '03', '05', '06')
                       then ';'+mcp.N5_6_TREATMENT_TYPE_3
                       else ''
                   end) +
                 (case when mcp.N5_6_TREATMENT_TYPE_4 in ('01', '02', '03', '05', '06')
                       then ';'+mcp.N5_6_TREATMENT_TYPE_4 
                       else ''
                   end)
                ), 1, 1, '')
     ELSE NULL
 END) as PlannedTreatmentType
```

`stuff()` replaces an arbitrary sequence of characters with another value.  With the arguments `1, 1, ''`, it removes the first character of the string.  Notice that the semicolon is now at the beginning rather than the end of the values.

By the way, storing these values in one row looks could be a mistake.  Perhaps you should consider having a table that has one row per entity (patient maybe) and one row per treatment type.

Comment: Gordon Linoff - Does the stuff function require 4 arguments? Also does this script remove the leading semi-colon? Thank you

Comment: @PaulStevens . . . The `stuff()` function requires four arguments and it should be removing the leading semicolon (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx).